# Append numeric value to binary string

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

**tl;dr**: Given `x,i = b'', 10`, how can I concatenate `i` onto `x`, resulting in `x == b'\x10'`?

I'm trying to encode a number in Python as a [varint](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints) as a header for a protobuf encoding.

Here's the code I have:

```
def encode_varint(value):
    buf = b''
    while True:
        byte = value & 0x7f
        value >>= 7
        if value:
            buf += chr(byte | 0x80)
        else:
            buf += chr(byte)
            break
    return buf
```

However, this fails because I cannot append a string to bytes.

How do I efficiently take an integer value and append it to a binary string?

Comment: The only option I've gotten that 'works' is `buf += chr(byte).encode('ascii')`, but that does not smell efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# option 1 (reportedly slower)
buf = b''
buf += bytes([byte])

# option 2 (reportedly faster)
buf = bytearray()
buf.append(byte)
```